# Sublime Text 3 Command B not running

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I downloaded Sublime Text 3 and now I am trying to run a simple python code in it. The code seems to have run when I run `Command + B`, but I don't see any output:

[image]

I am on Mac OS X El Capitan. I can't seem to see what's the issue here. Sublime has always printed the output for correctly formatted python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely using the python syntax check, press COMMAND+SHIFT+B to select what to build with, select python and after that COMMAND+B should work as you expected. Alternatively go under tools/Build with.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure when I changed it to syntax check.