# Sublime Text 3 Command+B on macOS

Tags: build, sublimetext3, build-system

I had <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> running `Build` on multiple languages (PHP, Python, etc.) under:

```
Tools > Build
```

Most recently, I have added:

```
quite: "true"
```

and it was working just fine. After a recent restart, it does not display the window underneath, that use to show the result of running.

Looked into some posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109372/sublime-text-3-command-b-not-running), yet could not figure it out.

Which settings should I be checking for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under,

```
Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings
```

in Preferences.sublime-settings-User file, changing,

```
show_panel_on_build: false,
```

to:

```
show_panel_on_build: true,
```

solved the problem.